# EditText On A Popup Window

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, popupwindow

I am developing on Android 2.2 using Java. 
I put an editText on a PopupWindow and it's not working.
It acts like a disabled edit text, clicking on the edit text won't show the soft keyboard.
How can I add an edit text on a popupWindow?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I have resolved the problem like this: I put the `popupWindow.setFocusable(true);` and now it's working. It seems that the edit text which was on a pop window didn't have focus because the popup window didn't have focus.

Comment: i was trying as you suggests but this is not helping.

Comment: but there is still a issue that is when u long press edittext marker doesnot appear nor it gives clipboard paste

Answer (score 47):

Just try:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

alert.setTitle("Title");
alert.setMessage("Message");

// Set an EditText view to get user input 
final EditText input = new EditText(this);
alert.setView(input);

alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

  // Do something with value!
  }
});

alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
    // Canceled.
  }
});

alert.show();
```

Comment: popup window almost took my day  and it took min to solve my issue thanks buddy

Answer (score 0):

Does the EditText definitely have the android:editable property set to true? If it's false it will be disabled as you describe.

Answer (score 0):

```
popWindow.setFocusable(true);
popWindow.update();
```

It will work.

Answer (score 0):

call this code from any listener

```
private void popUpEditText() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Comments");

        final EditText input = new EditText(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        input.setLayoutParams(lp);
        builder.setView(input);

        // Set up the buttons
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

             // do something here on OK 

            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        builder.show();

    }
```