# How to enable selection markers for EditText in PopupWindow?

Tags: android

I'm using a `EditText` in a `PopupWindow`. It shows OK, but the selection markers do not show up in the `EditText`. Neither does the Options menu change when I long press in the `EditText`. In LogCat I see a warning

> TextView does not support text selection. Action mode cancelled.

As a result, the `EditText` cannot copy/paste text from the clipboard.
Is there any way to get the "normal" `EditText` behaviour in a `PopupWindow`?

This code shows the problem, but I have also tried lots of variations:

```
EditText edit = new EditText(getContext());
edit.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow(edit, 100, 100, true);
popup.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
popup.showAtLocation(this, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, 100, 200);
```

Comment: I think here is what you need:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4134117/edittext-on-a-popup-window

Comment: No, that is not relevant to the problem I was having.

Comment: this seems an issue right now. see this http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=62508

You can use Dialog instead of PopupWindow if requirements allow so.

Comment: Or try setting popupWindow.setFocusable(true);

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
   editText.setSelectAllOnFocus(true);
```

Comment: No, that is not relevant to the problem I was having. I can select the text OK, but the markers do not appear. Alos, this question is 2 1/2 years old: I worked around the problem with a completely different approach.

Comment: Sorry , while searching I came to see this question. Any way , You got any solution now ?

Comment: No, not for this specific problem. I ended up using a DialogFragment rather than a popup window containing an EditView. Not what I wanted, but I coudl not find a way to make the popup window work.