# Android: "TextView does not support text selection. Action mode cancelled"

Tags: android

"TextView does not support text selection. Action mode cancelled."

I get this error when I try to bring up the context menu in an EditText in a PopupWindow in Android. The selection markers also do not work.

The question has been asked a number of times but has stayed unanswered:

[How to enable selection markers for EditText in PopupWindow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8035159/how-to-enable-selection-markers-for-edittext-in-popupwindow)

[PopupWindow not triggering sytem context dialog on EditText long-press](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13248581/popupwindow-not-triggering-sytem-context-dialog-on-edittext-long-press)

I am just another person dealing with the same issue. Any ideas?

Answer (score 15):

I have check around one hour, i found the solution: setwidth = wrapcontent (it's working with me)

Comment: Yes, it works because the TextView has to layout again. You can trace the `setText` method to understand why. But layout a view is expansive. It's an old bug of Android which google just don't want to fix it.

Comment: Worked for me on Android 6.0.0!

Comment: OMG, you are a life saver! WTF is that bug seriously... they could at least state something in the documentation.

Answer (score 5):

If `TextView`, have you tried `textView.setTextIsSelectable(true);`
Or if `EditText`, `editText.setSelectAllOnFocus(true);`

Comment: Hi Yojimbo, thanks for your reply, it is an EditText that I am dealing with. I tried editText.setSelectAllOnFocus(true) but I get the same error. Originally I had issues bring the keyboard too but I found an answer to that. I needed to make the PopupWindow focusable which I did in the constructor.

Comment: As EditText extends TextView, the setTextIsSelectable method is also available for it. It did work in my case. SelectAllOnFocus attribute changes the selection mode on click: from placing the cursor in click position (if false), to selecting all provided text (if true).

Answer (score 4):

I believe this is an Android bug, and I just reported it as such: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=62508

We will see whether Google agrees.

Answer (score 4):

try

```
et.setTextIsSelectable(true);
et.setFocusable(true);
et.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
```

Answer (score 3):

Check if you have

`android:focusable="false"` or

`android:focusableInTouchMode="false"` in your `xml` layout.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced PopupWindow with [DialogFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html), that solved my problem. You may try same. Also, I observed DialogFragment is more stable and I recommend it over PopupWindow. I faced multiple issues with PopupWindow, those were fixed when I started using DialogFragment.

I did not set selectAllOnFocus property.