# textview textIsSelectable="true" not working in Listview

Tags: android, listview, textview

```
 <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtSender"
                    style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/sender_bubble"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:maxEms="11"
                    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:paddingRight="15dp"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:text="1234567"
                    android:autoLink="all"
                    android:textColor="@color/color_black"
                    android:textIsSelectable="true"
                    android:visibility="visible" />
```

This is my textview in customcell. When i click on textview it is not allowing me to select the text in textview. It is working perfect in my xperia 4.2.2 but when i run the same code in device having version 4.4.4, it is not working.

> NOTE :  When i set the same    android:textIsSelectable="true" property to the Textview which is not in Listview, it works fine in 4.4.4. Listview just move to bottom  and resets to its original position within half of a second.

Comment: Try to add this properties android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false" to your textview.

Comment: android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"  in your list item xml

Comment: @HareshChhelana : I have tried by adding this 2 properties but it not seems to b working

Comment: @MeenalSharma : android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants" also not working

Comment: Refer below link, may it will help you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15857755/android-textview-does-not-support-text-selection-action-mode-cancelled

Comment: @Beena , any hack worked for you ? I am having same problem.

Comment: @Beena: What you edited in question?

Comment: @Palak : Just formatted. Highlighted text that it is creating issue above 4.4.4

Comment: @Beena : Still no any solution work from below ans?

Comment: @Palak : nope. Didn't find feasible solution for text selection in listview. Even faced same issue in some standard apps like whatspp.

Comment: @Beena: Ok, Did you concentrate on Listview focusable?

Comment: @Palak : Yes. Not working

Comment: @Benaa: Could you elaborate your requirements? Do you want to select particular portion from display text or whole text?

Comment: Have you solved this problem?

Answer (score 4):

In my case it wasn't working because I had textView in xml layout with android:visibility="gone" property and made it visible later in adapter code. So, you need call this after you makes textview visible

```
textView.setTextIsSelectable(true);
```

Comment: It works. However, not fully. It seems like you can select the text of TextView. But, the screen resizes and then the selected block disappears right away. So, It just changes the screen and that's it. You may need to prevent that changes or something.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"​` in the recyclerview or listview to prevent the blocking of selection

Also, change the textview layout width from `match_parent` to `wrap_content` to prevent the selectable text feature to be disabled when reusing the text cell.

Comment: We are using `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` for some. What is the alternative of line which will work with `textIsSelectable`?

Answer (score -1):

Remove the textIsSelectable, instead use:

```
android:inputType="textMultiLine"
```

The text will be selectable and editable.