# TextView with android:textIsSelectable="true" not working in listview

Tags: android, textview, selection

I know it's similar to [textview textIsSelectable="true" not working in Listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26380855/textview-textisselectable-true-not-working-in-listview).

Everything is fine when `TextView` is along, copy, parse. But when it's in list's item. I long click in `Textview`, The copy and parse menu seems appeal in top(`ActionBar`), but it dismisses in half a second.

I guess, the `ListView` is pushed down, so it's recall `getView()`. Ok, It's my guess.

Can anyone helps me.

My English is poor. If it's unclear, forgive me....

Thanks

My getView:

```
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_list, parent, false);
            }
            TextView textView = (TextView) convertView;
            textView.setFocusable(true);
            textView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(textView.getText())) {
                textView.setText("fdafdafdafkdsfjkldsfjioewjfiodsajlf" + position);
            }
            return convertView;
```

My item_list.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:padding="20dp"
          android:textIsSelectable="true"
          android:id="@+id/textView"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">

</TextView>
```

If it goes normal, the copy and parse menu comes:

[image]

But in `ListView`, the action bar menu pushed `ListView` down so `ListView` let this menu gone?

Comment: issue is textview is not getting focus. but if u set focusable true for textview, it might make your listitem focusable false

Comment: i m telling textview.setfocusable(true) and textview.text.setfocusableintouchmode(true).