# selection markers on textview in android

Tags: android, textview

I have used `textView.setTextIsSelectable(true)` or `android:textIsSelectable="true"` on textview. It is working somewhere but on some textviews it is showing the below error.

```
W/TextView: TextView does not support text selection. Action mode cancelled.
```

**I have tried**

```
 android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Also on textviews but it is also not working, can you please help me to figure out why it is working on some textviews and not working on others.

Thanks a lot in advanced.

Comment: Are there any differences in the way the two textViews are being used?

Answer (score 0):

As answered by [Yojimbo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2225646/yojimbo) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15857781):

> If `TextView`, have you tried `textView.setTextIsSelectable(true);`
>   Or if `EditText`, `editText.setSelectAllOnFocus(true);`

Hope this is Help you.

Comment: Please Refer Link:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15857755/android-textview-does-not-support-text-selection-action-mode-cancelled

Comment: I am using textView and already tried textView.setTextIsSelectable(true); , but it is not making any change.

Yes, these textviews are inside a listview, will that be any problem with this ??