# Can't edit an edittext in a popup window without dismissing and recalling it first

Tags: android, android-edittext, popupwindow

I am using a popup window to display some information and have an edit button that allows that information to be changed.  I am loading all textviews, buttons and edittext fields and hiding/showing them as needed.  The edittext fields are not letting me edit them.  I have tried the below suggestion about setting focusable to true, but that isn't working.  Any other suggestions?

Tried this: [EditText On A Popup Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4134117/edittext-on-a-popup-window)

EDIT:  Below is part of my code.  I've just included the parts for initializing the edittext and showing the popup contents since everything else is working, just not the edittext.  I am using a tablelayout, and when the user clicks a row, the popup window displays.  Keep in mind I'm still pretty new to Java and Android!

EDIT #2:  The softkeyboard was not showing when the edittext was selected, but now it will show if I dismiss the popup once and then call it again.  I then tried forcing the softkeyboard to display, and it showed behind the popup (another problem).  I was able to select the number 1 since it was barely showing behind the popup window, but it didn't seem to work either.  The fix was the same here: dismiss the popup window and recall it.  **So my remaining problem is being able to type into the edittext without having to dismiss the popup once and recall it.**  As such, I am changing the title of this question.

```
row1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    final EditText pwETBrand = (EditText) vPopUp.findViewById(R.id.et_editbrand);

    if (!infoClick) {
        infoClick = true;

        // Popup elements initialized earlier
        pwInfo.showAtLocation(llInfo, Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
        pwInfo.update(0, 0, llMain.getWidth()-50, llMain.getHeight()-100);
        pwInfo.setFocusable(true);
```

....

```
        // Hide some elements initially until "EDIT" button is pressed
        pwETBrand.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

....

```
        // When EDIT button is pressed, hide default elements, and show edit elements
        pwEdit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v2) {
                pwETBrand.setVisivility(View.VISIBLE);
                // Other element settings go here
                pwInfo.setFocusable(true);
            }
        )};
```

....

```
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show some code? I think maybe the view focus order cause this

Comment: I have added a few edits, though the scope of the question has changed a bit, as shown in EDIT #2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have implemented a solution, though it may not be the best solution.  I have set a boolean field at the class initialization that checks if the popupwindow has ever been called.  If it has not yet been called, then it will immediately dismiss the popupwindow and re-open it since my problem is in the popupwindow initialization.

```
    pwInfo.showAtLocation(llInfo, Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
    pwInfo.update(0, 0, llMain.getWidth()-50, llMain.getHeight()-100);
    pwInfo.setFocusable(true);

    if (pwFirst) {
        pwFirst = false;
        pwInfo.dismiss();
        pwInfo.showAtLocation(llInfo, Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
        pwInfo.update(0, 0, llMain.getWidth()-50, llMain.getHeight()-100);
        pwInfo.setFocusable(true);
    }
```

Not the best solution, but it works.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,true);
```

works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Use Below Link's Code for that, it may help you.

[Popup With Edittext](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-prompt-user-input-dialog-example/)

Comment: Good reference, and thank you.  I cannot vote up your answer, as I do not yet have enough reputation to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you create a `PopupWindow` you must put `true` in `focusable` like that :

```
 PopupWindow(View contentView, int width, int height, boolean focusable) 

  final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,true);
```

good luck