# keyboard doesn't display in android popup view

Tags: android, popupwindow

I've got a popup layout inflator with EditText fields. It is opened inside my activity when a button is pressed. I then ask for input information through the popup window. When I press any of the EditText fields the keyboard doesn't display. Does the popup View not support interaction?

Here is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:background="@android:color/background_light">
 <LinearLayout 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical" 
 android:layout_margin="1dp"
 android:background="@android:color/darker_gray">
 >
 <LinearLayout 
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical" 
  >
  <TextView
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Fill in the information." />

  <RelativeLayout
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/textView1"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"

           android:text="Field ID or Name"
           android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

       <EditText
           android:id="@+id/fieldname"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
           android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
           android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
           android:ems="10" >

           <requestFocus />
       </EditText>

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/enterWidth"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="Width of Implement - Feet or Meters"
           android:layout_below="@+id/fieldname"
           android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />



       <EditText
           android:id="@+id/width"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:ems="10"
            android:layout_below="@+id/enterWidth"

           android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

            <TextView
           android:id="@+id/units"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="Units"
           android:layout_below="@+id/width"
           android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />




        <RadioGroup 
            android:id="@+id/radiogroup"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_below="@+id/units"
android:orientation="vertical">
<RadioButton android:id="@+id/standard"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Standard - feet, ac, mph"
    android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>
<RadioButton android:id="@+id/metric"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Metric - m, ha, kph"
    android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>
</RadioGroup>


        <TextView
           android:id="@+id/comments"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="Field Comments"
           android:layout_below="@+id/radiogroup"
           android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />


           <EditText
      android:id="@+id/commentlines"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_below="@+id/comments"
      android:ems="10"
      android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

  </RelativeLayout>



  <Button
      android:id="@+id/startbutton"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Begin Spraying" />
  </LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

After digging I found this similar post:

[EditText On A Popup Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4134117/edittext-on-a-popup-window)

The key is to make the PopupWindow focusable.

This can be done by:

```
popupWindow.setFocusable(true);
```